# How to extract long URL from email with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail-imap

I need to extract a very long URL (example below) from an email message that I grab using Gmail's IMAP.

```
https://example.com/account/resetpassword?code=e8EkT%2B48uMCHr3Sq4QZVr0%2FVHrTBwQvhYwubjeaKozn29I7VGvWSYNO6VNRLXCK230P%2FklDrFC6BpPI7OF%2F5yawHlux80jqTBhTq2QRS4r7sEnSM9qKV1mIXkTzx%2B5tjakgElg%3D%3D&returnUrl=example.com
```

However, when I try to print the grabbed message, I notice that my long URL has some extra things like `=\r\n` and `3D` inside of it (see examples below) or it is split in several lines by `=`.

```
https://example.com/account/resetpa=\r\nssword?code=3De8EkT%2B48uMCHr3Sq4QZVr0%2FVHrTBwQvhYwubjeaKozn29I7VGvWSYNO6V=\r\nNRLXCK230P%2FklDrFC6BpPI7OF%2F5yawHlux80jqTBhTq2QRS4r7sEnSM9qKV1mIXkTzx%2B5=\r\ntjakgElg%3D%3D&returnUrl=3Dexample.com

https://example.com/account/resetpa=
ssword?code=3De8EkT%2B48uMCHr3Sq4QZVr0%2FVHrTBwQvhYwubjeaKozn29I7VGvWSYNO6V=
NRLXCK230P%2FklDrFC6BpPI7OF%2F5yawHlux80jqTBhTq2QRS4r7sEnSM9qKV1mIXkTzx%2B5=
tjakgElg%3D%3D&returnUrl=3Dexample.com
```

How can I make sure that nothing is added to the long URL so that I could use it later to open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that format with `=` and `3D` is called quoted printable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

You could try using `quopri.decodestring(string)`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html

Answer (score 0):

`"\r\n"` is a carriage return, which you can get rid of by using `urlstring.replace("\r\n", "")`. `%3D` means `=`([source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)), but I don't see why this would be an issue for you. The only issue is the carriage returns, which print your URL on different lines.